# chmod not working correctly in Docker

Tags: permissions, docker, chmod

I'm building a Docker image for my `Symfony` app and I need to give permission to apache server to write into cache and log folders

```
#Dockerfile
FROM php:7-apache

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y libicu-dev  freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl mbstring \
&& a2enmod rewrite

COPY app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY app/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY ./ /var/www/html

RUN find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
RUN find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/app/cache /var/www/html/app/logs
```

When I build this image with `docker build -t myname/symfony_apps:latest .` and run the container with `docker run -p 8080:80 myname/symfony_apps:latest`.
Apache log is flooded by permission denied errors , the strange thing that I've checked with `ls -a` and permissions are fine. and when I run chmod from container's bash , apache permission issues are gone and the app works well

**The situation**

**Running chmod commands from dockerfile:** permissions are changed but apache still complains about permission denied.
**Running chmod same commands with bash inside the container:** permissions are changed and my app is running

Any idea , Am I missing something, maybe I should add root user somewhere in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your docker command that runs the built image.

Comment: I'm seeing an extra space in your last command (I'm on my phone, so I can't be sure). As the permission problem seems to be with the log directory, change the last line to: ```
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/app/cache /var/www/html/app/logs
```

Comment: Okay .. I edited the question :)

Comment: that extra space was a typo

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem.  If I use your dockerfile and set up some dummy files locally, permissions are correct and everything Just Works.  I can boot a container and access content via a web browser.  Can you update your question to include specific error messages?  Are you certain your Apache configuration (`apache2.conf`) is not causing a problem? Do the errors go away if you do not install `apache2.conf`?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue and it seems that there is some bug in docker or overlay2 if directory content is created in one layer and its permissions are changed in other.

As a workaround you could copy sources to temporary directory:

```
COPY . /src
```

And then move it to `/var/www/html` and setup permissions (in one `RUN` command):

```
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html && mv /src /var/www/html &&\
    find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; &&\
    find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; &&\
    chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/app/cache /var/www/html/app/logs
```

Also I created [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/29922).

Comment: I was going to dig into my old source code this night to see how I've solved this , then I remembered that tmp directory trick .. hope this didn't took you a lot of time to solve XD

Comment: this is still an open issue?!

Answer (score 18):

Try adding :

```
USER root
```

It worked for me.

Comment: If you switch to root, you should probably switch back to the previous user when you finish or you are decreasing the security and compatibility of the container. Some Kubernetes implementations by default won't run a container as root for example.

Comment: for me switching to root doesn't help

Comment: Alternative to switching user, you can also use a multistage build. Perhaps not as useful for PHP images, but anything that requires an application to be built before it is run could benefit from that approach.

Answer (score 11):

The default shell of RUN in Docker is /bin/sh and this is where the permissions not being set correctly actually has a problem.

**But you can change to just use /bin/bash instead to easily fix, notice before and after directory listing**

```
Step 7/9 : RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls -la; chmod +x gitlab-properties-builder.sh; ls -la'
---> Running in dc57ae77aa67

drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      103 Mar  8 17:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       46 Mar  8 17:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root        6 Mar  7 20:47 config
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2340 Mar  7 21:20 gitlab-properties-builder.sh
-rw-r--r--. 5 root root 57325770 Mar  5 14:39 gitlab-scm-collector-2.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar

drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       42 Mar  8 17:56 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       61 Mar  8 17:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root        6 Mar  7 20:47 config
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     2340 Mar  7 21:20 gitlab-properties-builder.sh
-rw-r--r--. 5 root root 57325770 Mar  5 14:39 gitlab-scm-collector-2.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
---> 8b5de6e348d3
```

Comment: Why is `/bin/bash -c 'chmod +x file'` is working and not `/bin/sh -c 'chmod +x file'` ?

Comment: your is better solution . it worked for me . thanks .

Comment: Also, using the new buildkit helps in a number of areas including this one.  Give it a try. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/

Answer (score 8):

This issue is likely the result of a `VOLUME` definition inside the upstream Dockerfile. When a volume is defined in the Dockerfile, you can add files with a `COPY` or `ADD` command directly into the image. However, a `RUN` line will:

- Create a temporary container using the image definition as of the current point of the dockerfile

  - That temporary container will have an anonymous volume mounted as you or a parent image specified inside the Dockerfile
  - The anonymous volume will be initialized from the contents of the image
- Your command will run inside the container

  - If you list the directory during this `RUN` command, you will see your changes applied, but those changes have been applied to the volume
- When your run command completes, docker will capture the changes to the container

  - These changes can be seen with a `docker diff` if you do not delete the temporary containers (you can run a build with `--rm=false` to have them remain)
  - These changes will not include the anonymous volume contents because they do not exist inside the temporary container filesystem, volumes are separate

Because of this behavior, you have the options to:

1. you can copy your files to a different directory and change the permissions there
2. you can fix the permissions on your host so they get copied in with those permissions directly
3. you can remove the volume from either your image, get the upstream image to remove their volume definition, or you can rebuild your own copy of the upstream image without the volume definition and base your images off of that

Note that inside the current php images, it appears that the volume has been removed, which means we effectively have option 3.

Comment: This volume/build behaviour is absolutly logical but I missed it : I'm really a dumb boy, shame on me ! - and thanks a lot for your very clear explanation

Comment: unfortunately you cant remove upstream volumes.

Comment: @QkiZ I was suggesting you talk to upstream, not that there's a technical way to have docker do that, other than the third part of the third option.

Answer (score 1):

I just made an experiment with the following:

```
FROM alpine

LABEL MAINTAINER="YIMGA YIMGA Salathiel Genèse"
RUN apk add --no-cache inotify-tools
CMD [ "./script.sh" ]
WORKDIR /opt/app/
COPY src/ /opt/app/
RUN chmod a+x *.sh
```

And it just works great.

## However

When I override that executable file through docker-compose volumes, the `execute` permission is simply like rolled-back - technically overrode to original file permission.

**The fix for dev mode** is simply to `chmod a+x yourfile` from host, which will be inherited at compose volume mounting.

Comment: The entire goal of a volume is to mount files from somewhere other than the image, so if you fix your image and mount a volume over top of that, by design you will not see your image changes. Depending on why you have a volume, the answer may be to simply not have a volume.

Comment: Yes [BMitch](https://serverfault.com/users/351549/bmitch), I totally agree as for the effect of mounting volume that override container fs from docker built image, but... During development, you surely don't want to rebuild/restart your container in order to test each and every change you do. In this latter scenario do you want that mount a volume that overrides docker built image fs. And I faced the same issue before landing here. I wasn't convicted by either answer explanations and tested each of them. It is only then that I understood what it going on and posted my observations...

Comment: ...and I suspect the scenario I experienced is the same as that of he who asked the question.

Comment: The OP indicated they saw the issue with just a `docker run` command and no external volume mounts.

Comment: Oups - I missed that aspect... The right answer for the right question title, but not the described scenario. Then may I mention that I could not reproduce the above mentioned issue.

Comment: ```overrode to original file permission``` looks like this was my issue. In my local setup, I don't want to rebuild image every time I made src changes. so I commented out COPY line and use VOLUME in docker-compose. This gave me similiar situation with OP, I will check if it can be resolved by also *comment out* RUN chmod line